# Which part of the given sentence has an error and why?

Tags: errors

Below is the sentence, divided into four parts:

> (a) I will try
>   (b) to be on time
>   (c) but do not worry
>   (d) when I am late.

Comment: You need a comma before _but_, (as the two independent clauses each have a subject), but secondarily 'd' would sound better as _if I am late_, to remove the contradiction between trying better but being late. If this is a test question, c. If real life, c and d.

Comment: @YosefBaskin That changes the meaning.

Comment: @deadrat - You are right.

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Answer (score 1):

D. When you try to do something, there's a chance you may succeed. So, saying 'when I am late' presumes you will fail in your quest. 'If I am late' fits with the first part.